# Linked list error in adding element at beginning

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program of adding element in a Linked list.
While trying to execute the given python code, there is an error:

> "local variable 'head' referenced before  assignment"

Here is the code which I tried:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
def createList(n):
    d=int(input('enter  element:'))
    global head
    head=Node(d)
    head.next=None
    temp=head
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        d=int(input('enter element:'))
        node=Node(d)
        node.next=None
        temp.next=node
        temp=temp.next

def printList():
    temp=head
    while temp is not None:
        print(temp.data,' ',end='')
        temp=temp.next

def insertData(data):
    node=Node(data)
    node.next=None
    temp=head
    while temp.next is not None:
        temp=temp.next
    
    temp.next=node
def insertBefore(b):
    n=Node(b)
    n.next=head
    head=n
    
    

n=int(input('Enter the number of elements:'))
createList(n)
printList()
print()
data=int(input('enter element to add at end of list:'))
insertData(data)
printList()
print()
b=int(input('enter element to add in begining:'))
insertBefore(b)
printList()
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score 0):

In all of your functions you've copied the value of head into temp when the system doesn't know what head is until it reaches down to the insertBefore(b) function plus within that same function uve referenced head and assigned a value to it after you've used it so it should go from:

```
def insertBefore(b):
    n=Node(b)
    n.next=head
    head=n
```

to

```
def insertBefore(b):
    n=Node(b)
    head=n
    n.next=head
```

and then put that function on top of all the other functions